# How do I store previous login date and time in a .bin file with it being shown in a listbox in a different form?

Tags: c#, winforms, bin

I have been trying to figure out how to show all the previous log-ins (the date and time) in a listbox in a different form. I have 3 forms (The login form - Prijava.cs, The main window form - GlavnoOkno.cs, The Evidence for logging in form - Evidenca.cs)

The current issue I am having is that the list aswell as the listbox seems to only save the most recent log in date and time. And the .bin file updates whenever I write onto it with the newest log in date and time. I want it to log all the previous ones aswell, while the application is open and clear them when the form closes.

I achieved this with this code in the Evidenca form:

```
private void Evidenca_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox.DataSource = Prijava.LastLog;
}
```

And this is my code from the login form (Prijava):

```
public partial class Prijava : Form
{
    public static List<string> LastLog = new List<string>();

    private void Prijava_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LastLog = new List<string>();

        bool file = File.Exists("Katja.bin");

        if (!file)
        {
            File.Create("Katja.bin").Close();
            saveLogin(LogD);
        }
    
        this.Hide();

    }

    public static DateTime LastLoginTime = DateTime.Now;

    public static string LogDanes = LastLoginTime.ToString();

    public string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + "logins.bin";

    public void btnvpis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vpisanoime = txtime.Text;    
        string vpisanogeslo = txtgeslo.Text;

        if (vpisanoime == "katja" && vpisanogeslo == "1234")  
            //Checks if the password and username match the written in textbox
        {
            //Opens up main window form and hides login form
            GlavnoOkno f2 = new GlavnoOkno();
            f2.Show();
            Visible = false;

            //Is supposed to add the date and time of logging in(pressing the log in button) to list
            Prijava.LastLoginTime = DateTime.Now;
            Prijava.LogD = LastLoginTime.ToString();
            LastLog.Add(LogD);

            //Is supposed to call function and write the datetime LogD into .bin file
            saveLogin(LogD);
        }
    }

    public void saveLogin(string logD)
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("Katja.bin", FileMode.Create)))
        {
            writer.Write(LogD);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me solve this issue I am having.

If anything doesn't make sense, please comment and ill try to respond and fix it as fast as I can.

Comment: Simply use the [File.AppendAllText(String, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext). It automatically appends to an existing file and creates a file if none exists. No need to open or close etc., `File.AppendText(path, FlogD);` does everything.

Comment: Where would I use this method?

Comment: Well, in the `saveLogin` method obviously. And remove the `File.Exists`, and `File.Create` thing. It is not required anymore. `public void saveLogin(string logD) {  File.AppendAllText(path, logD); }`. Also specify the whole path, not just the filename. in my previous comment I erroneously wrote `File.AppendText`. It should be `File.AppendAllText`.

Comment: Okay, so now the .bin file isnt getting created anymore? and its not working :l And this doesnt really answer my question or fix the problem im having

Comment: Load the file into the ListBox: `listBox.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines(path);`. The statement `File.AppendAllText(path, logD);` creates the file if it does not exist already.

Comment: Ok this does work, but it doesnt add more than one date and time to the list and listbox. It only edits the one already added before? Do i have to add the variable with the date and time differently?